# map my url with window 2008 r2 for a tomcat web application

Tags: tomcat, uri

I have developed a web application using jsp/servelt technology, now i have hosted in my company windows server by using tomcat web server. when i want to go to the application i have to type my server name and the 8080 port no. I want to remove this and want to use my web application name instead of the server name. hope a quick answer.

example:

now  (http://my server name:8080/)

what i want (http://my application name)

Answer (score 0):

The default HTTP port is 80. However, if you already run a webserver like Apache, lightttpd or nginx, you should instead reverse-proxy the 8080 URI and close down Port 8080 in your firewall.

Comment: please can you give me a stepwise procedure to make this achieve..